# Get the django user in save while using django.form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, user-permissions

I have a problem getting the user in django when I use django forms. My code looks something like this.

The view:

```
@login_required
def something(request):
    item = ItemForm(request.POST)
    item.save(user=request.user)
```

The form:

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs['user'] 
        super(ItemForm, self).save(user=user)
```

The model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100,)

    def check_permissions(self, user):
        return user.groups.filter(name='group').exists()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.check_permissions(kwargs['user']):
            super(Item, self).save()
```

My problem is that when I call the default save in ItemForm I get an error because the user param is unexpected. I need the user in the model to make the permission check but I dont know how to get it.

Comment: Why don't you do the check in the view?

Comment: In my opinion it makes a pretty redundant code if I have more than one view that use the model and if I make it a service or something like that is still easier to forget a check. Is there any reason to check permissions in the view instead of the model?

Comment: You could use [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) view decorator to avoid redundancy.

Comment: I think @aumo comment is the best approach but in this specific problem  was not an option for me because a complex permission sistem. But thanks!

Comment: And you can always create your custom decorators for checking permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The way I found was to save the form without the user but with the commit flag set to False and then calling the function save from the model with the user param.

The form save method now looks like this

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    item = super(ItemForm, self).save(commit=False)
    item.save(user=kwargs['user'])
```